# Cloudinary, jQuery limit to single image upload

Tags: php, jquery, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary, JQuery with PHP but can't find any option on how to limit upload to just one file.

In my cl_image_upload_tag I tried setting  "html" => array("multiple" => false))); but this has no effect.

I read the Cloudinary documentation but couldn't see any option for it, any ideas thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the line from;

```
echo cl_image_upload_tag('xx', array("tags" => "xxxx", "callback" => $cors_location, "html" => array("multiple" => true)));
```

To this;

```
echo cl_image_upload_tag('xx', array("tags" => "xxxx", "callback" => $cors_location ));
```

ie. removing the multiple did the trick, setting it to false didnt work, nor did changing limitMultiFileUploads in the js file.